# Switching between windows with selenium and firefox

Tags: java, firefox, selenium

So, I am trying to add email aliases to my Gmail account automatically and I wrote this code to transfer the aliases from the list to Gmail. However, I am facing a problem with finding the window handle.

My code:

```
        for (int p = 0; p < InstagramAievx.list.getItemCount(); p++) {

        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[role=link][class=sA][idlink='']")).click();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        handleMultipleWindows("Gmail - Add another email address you own");
        driver.findElement(By.id("cfn")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.name("cfn")).sendKeys(InstagramAievx.gmailname.getText());
        driver.findElement(By.id("focus")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.name("cfa")).sendKeys(InstagramAievx.list.getItem(m));
        if (driver.findElement(By.id("cfia")).isSelected()) {
            driver.findElement(By.id("cfia")).click();
        }
        ;
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("css=[type=submit][value=Next Step »]")).click();

        m++;
        handleMultipleWindows("Settings - " + InstagramAievx.email.getText() + "@gmail.com - Gmail");
    }

}
```

The handleMultipleWindows method:

```
    public void handleMultipleWindows(String windowTitle) {
    Set<String> windows = driver.getWindowHandles();

    for (String window : windows) {
        driver.switchTo().window(window);
        if (driver.getTitle().contains(windowTitle)) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Window not found. The browser window may have been closed.
Command duration or timeout: 24 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11 19:03:33'
System info: host: 'ABJ-PC', ip: '192.168.1.4', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_74'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=44.0.2, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 0482ba0b-052c-483a-90f5-2a4d4a55dcf2
*** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=css=[type=submit][value=Next Step »]}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByCssSelector(RemoteWebDriver.java:492)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector.findElement(By.java:430)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:355)
    at com.example.tests.TestInstagram.Gmail(TestInstagram.java:247)
    at com.example.tests.InstagramAievx$11.actionPerformed(InstagramAievx.java:304)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The new window you are trying to switch to is actually new tab, not new window. You can switch to new tab using this method in some of the browsers, but not in FireFox. I suggest you do it in Chrome.

Comment: I get the exact same error. I don't know what is causing that. @Guy